# Automation using selenium , testNG for Integrated highcharts graph

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to automate svg graphs that are integrated into console from 3rd party console. I tried many ways like listing all elements using tagname, and also by using cssSelector. No matter what I am using, it is always showing No such Element as it is not able to identify the element.Is there any way that I can use to find solution?

Comment: What console ??? Browser console?

Comment: Console here refers to normal website.

Comment: show as much code as U can (but minimal to problem show)

Comment: please show us HTML and Code (what u have tried so far)

Comment: WebElement Yellow=wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='clear left width100perct dashboard dashboard-fixed']/div[@class='clear left width45perct marginLeft15']/table[@class='tblDashboard']/tr[@class='report-container']/td[@class='report-widget txtCenter']/div[@id='highcharts-2']/g[@class='highcharts-series-group']/g[@class='highcharts-series highcharts-tracker']/Path[@fill='#6AA851']"));WebElement tootltip=wd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/svg/g[3]/path[1]"));Yellow.click();System.out.println("yellow color  =" +tootltip.getText());

Comment: above code is what I tried, I am not sure if I can share Html. But I can say that it is a stacked bar chart which will show text and score when hovered on it.What ever locator I am using, if is always showing that No such element message